# Count amount of received data - gnu/linux

Tags: linux, internet

How Can I count the received data from the internet.

I want to run my bash script and count how many MB it receive.

It could be stats for whole system.

Comment: This question is near serverfault, but stay linked to programmation...

Comment: Ok. I'll remember. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watch your network devices

```
ifconfig

ip -s link show

cat /proc/net/dev
```

or better use `iptables` whith specific counters, that let you quantize by protocol, kind of connexions, durations, etc...

create a counter rule with no `jump`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80
```

than watch them with

```
iptables -nvxL INPUT
```

(for playing with iptable, root access is needed).

Comment: Why amount of data in  /proc/net/dev sometimes resets ?

Comment: What do you mean by `sometimes`? As I know, driver module as to be unloaded in order to reset counters (`ifdown ... rmmod ... modprobe ... ifup` ). But maybe are you speaking about *loop* happening when all bits of integer counter are full (likely depending on your architecture).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pv command, see [man pv(1) page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv). Also you can try different bandwidth monitoring tools.